# Bone rotation deforms mesh in weird way

Tags: mesh, rigging, objects, armature, bones

I've made this tiger head rig, and started adding teeth. When I started to rig those teeth (as separate objects), I noticed they did not move with the head bone in a similar fashion. This was the case, however, until I noticed that the jaw/mouth itself was deforming when the head bone rotated, making the teeth not stay within the head. It does this for any direction.

[image]
^Every bone appears to be linked.

[image]
^Viewed straight-on appears normal.

[image]
^Rotating head makes it slack-jawed.

[image]
^Weight painting seems fine to me (but I'm very new). I also painted the teeth, but they don't deform strangely in the same way.

[File Download](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48124)

Answer (score 1):

The jaw-lower bones are acting to deform its jaw.

I cleaned some weights in jaw and all works fine now.

See the image below, the bone selected and some cleaning in law:

[image]

Comment: This works! There were multiple bones with slight weight painting on that jaw. I just need to clean it up better.